# How to run Hang Analyze Report in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, performance, database-administration

We are trying to schedule hanganalyze automatically if number of sessions are greater than 300 as it is too difficult to monitor database continuously and this issue happens only for a couple of minutes. Could you help us in creating procedure. Also could you confirm that if running this procedure has any impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

A hang analyze is done via oradebug, so you'd be looking at using SQL Plus to check session counts and then run it if needed, eg store this in a script

```
spool /tmp/checker.sql
select 
  case when count(*) > 300 then
    'oradebug setorapname reco' ||chr(10)||'oradebug -g all hanganalyze 3'
  else
    'REM do nothing'
  end
from v$session
spool off
@/tmp/checker.sql
```

and then have a SQL plus session that does:

```
conn / as sysdba
@script.sql
host sleep 60
@script.sql
host sleep 60
...
...
```

Comment: I have verified the command . It only print the oradebug hang analyze statement.

Comment: SQL> select
  2    case when count(*) > 50 then
  3      'oradebug setorapname reco' ||chr(10)||'oradebug -g all hanganalyze 3'
  4    else
  5      'REM do nothing'
  6    end
  7  from v$session;

CASEWHENCOUNT(*)>50THEN'ORADEBUGSETORAPNAMERECO'||CHR(1
-------------------------------------------------------
oradebug setorapname reco

Comment: Yes but you are spooling that command to a file and then running that  file.